# Is there a Python library that can parse RDF*?

Tags: library, python, rdf

Is there any Python library that can parse RDF*? Something to use until RDFLib implements it?

Comment: @Robert RDF is a W3C standard since 2004. see https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/

Comment: @Robert man, just click the tag